# pthread_self returning different values

Tags: c, pthreads

I am learning threads using C and found the following 'Hello World' program. When I am printing the vale of pthread_value() within the thread and outside the thread using pthread_join() the values returned by the two threads are completely different.

```
/******************************************************************************
* FILE: hello.c
* DESCRIPTION:
*   A "hello world" Pthreads program.  Demonstrates thread creation and
*   termination.
* AUTHOR: Blaise Barney
* LAST REVISED: 08/09/11
******************************************************************************/
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUM_THREADS     5

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;
   printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!, %ld\n", tid, pthread_self());
   long a=  pthread_self();
   //pthread_exit(NULL);
        long *p = &a;
   return p;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   void *status;
   long t;
   FILE* file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
   for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++){
     printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
     rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
     if (rc){
       printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
       exit(-1);
       }
     }
   for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS;t++){
     pthread_join(threads[t], &status);
     printf("%ld\n",(long)status);

        }
   /* Last thing that main() should do */
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Hint: What do you think happens when you return the address of a local variable and then try to dereference it in some other part of code?

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I realized my basics of C were not clear and spend 7-8 hours before using threads. I understand now where I went wrong :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `PrintHello()` function returns the address of a local variable. Trying to use that address after the function exits is undefined and anything can happen, from getting a garbage value to your program crashing. Plus instead of dereferencing that address to get at the value it points to (Assuming it was still valid, which, again, it's not), you cast the address to a long and print out the address itself. I doubt that's what you intended to do. The general approach should be to malloc enough memory in the thread to hold its return value, and returning that address. Then in the joining thread, dereference that returned address to get at the actual returned value, and free that memory when done.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was really a stupid question but it did not come to my mind that the variable is out of scope. I completed the basics of C to avoid similar situations